# MacOS and Environment variables

Tags: java, environment-variables, macos-high-sierra

I have set my environment variables in my `.bash_profile` file. I have `macOS 10.12.6`

It's looks like:

```
#MYENV environemnt
export MY_ENV=/Users/user_name/directory
```

I create a simple java code, that try to read all environment variables:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();

            for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
                System.out.println("name: " + envName);

            }
    }
```

If I run my code it prints only these varriables:

```
run:
name: PATH
name: J2D_PIXMAPS
name: SHELL
name: JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_3122
name: USER
name: TMPDIR
name: JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_2967
name: SSH_AUTH_SOCK
name: XPC_FLAGS
name: LD_LIBRARY_PATH
name: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
name: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
name: LOGNAME
name: LC_CTYPE
name: XPC_SERVICE_NAME
name: PWD
name: SHLVL
name: HOME
name: _
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

If I run `printenv` command from my terminal, i can see my environment variable.

So my problem is, why cannot my java application see all environment varriables?
Thank you!

Comment: Your code works for me when I execute it from the command line with `java`. Your `.bash_profile` isn't loaded when apps are launched; are you executing your code in an IDE?